# Javascript/jQuery differenciating between mobile devices and PCs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a datetime picker on some inputs on my webpage. The problem is that when using a mobile device and selecting the input, both the datetime picker and the mobile device keyboard will appear. By using the 'readonly' attribute on the input will fix this problem but will make the input not editable. What I want is to keep the input readonly on mobile devices and editable on PCs. I am looking for the best way to differenciate between mobile devices and PCs.

This is what i have so far:

```
if (/Mobi|Tablet|iPad|iPhone/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    $('.dtpicker').each(function(){
        $(this).prop('readonly', true);
    });
}
```

Any other method of preventing the default mobile keyboard from showing is welcomed.

Comment: look for the window size and handle on width < 720px (phone)

Comment: Just curious if `$(this).attr('readonly', true);` works as well, and does not hinder setting the value.

Comment: @yezzz It does not hinder the datetime picker or any script that sets the value to the input just prevents the user from editing the value.

Comment: @TypedSource I could just look for the window size, but what about android TVs and other PCs with touch screens?

Comment: ok, I thought you were letting you user only use the datepicker which I presume is a dropdown with buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afaik mobile keyboards use focus event to show the keyboard, and blur to hide it. If you remove the readonly attribute after focus it should not popup the keyboard.

Click event tends to be fired after focus so I've chosen that instead focus:

```
if (/Mobi|Tablet|iPad|iPhone/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
  $('.dtpicker').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('readonly', true)
      .on("click", function() {
        $(this).removeAttr('readonly');
      })
      .on("blur", function() {
        $(this).attr('readonly', true);
      })

  })
}
```